# Ошибка при переходе на CMS Bitrix 17

Tags: битрикс

Как это исправить?

```
    [TypeError] 
    Argument 1 passed to 
    Bitrix\Sale\Discount\Prediction\Manager::findFirstPredictionDiscount() must 
    be of the type array, null given, called in 
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/sale/lib/discount/prediction/manager.php on 
     line 88 (0)
/home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/sale/lib/discount/prediction/manager.php:418
#0: Bitrix\Sale\Discount\Prediction\Manager->findFirstPredictionDiscount(NULL, string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/sale/lib/discount/prediction/manager.php:88
#1: Bitrix\Sale\Discount\Prediction\Manager->getFirstPredictionTextByProduct(object, array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/components/bitrix/sale.prediction.product.detail/class.php:72
#2: CSalePredictionProductDetailComponent->executeComponent()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:585
#3: CBitrixComponent->includeComponent(string, array, object)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/main.php:1035
#4: CAllMain->IncludeComponent(string, string, array, object, array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/templates/sm_default/components/bitrix/catalog.element/catalog/template.php:1021
#5: include(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component_template.php:714
#6: CBitrixComponentTemplate->__IncludePHPTemplate(array, array, string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component_template.php:806
#7: CBitrixComponentTemplate->IncludeTemplate(array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:681
#8: CBitrixComponent->showComponentTemplate()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:629
#9: CBitrixComponent->includeComponentTemplate()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/lib/component/base.php:3870
#10: Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Base->loadData()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/lib/component/base.php:3849
#11: Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Base->initialLoadAction()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/lib/component/element.php:229
#12: Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Element->initialLoadAction()

#13: call_user_func(array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/lib/component/base.php:4034
#14: Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Base->doAction()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/iblock/lib/component/base.php:4052
#15: Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Base->executeComponent()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:585
#16: CBitrixComponent->includeComponent(string, array, object)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/main.php:1035
#17: CAllMain->IncludeComponent(string, string, array, object)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/templates/sm_default/components/bitrix/catalog/al/element.php:401
#18: include(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component_template.php:714
#19: CBitrixComponentTemplate->__IncludePHPTemplate(array, array, string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component_template.php:806
#20: CBitrixComponentTemplate->IncludeTemplate(array)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:681
#21: CBitrixComponent->showComponentTemplate()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:629
#22: CBitrixComponent->includeComponentTemplate(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/components/bitrix/catalog/component.php:168
#23: include(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:548
#24: CBitrixComponent->__includeComponent()
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/component.php:600
#25: CBitrixComponent->includeComponent(string, array, boolean)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/main.php:1035
#26: CAllMain->IncludeComponent(string, string, array, boolean)
    /home/bitrix/www/catalog/index.php:570
#27: include_once(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include/urlrewrite.php:159
#28: include_once(string)
    /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/urlrewrite.php:2
```

Comment: Очень не помешал бы текст файла `/home/bitrix/www/catalog/index.php`, в особенности контекста строки 570.

Так-то вам английским по белому предлагается передать в `Bitrix\Sale\Discount\Prediction\Manager::findFirstPredictionDiscount()` массив вместо "ничего".